# how to use js and css in custom module in magento 2.3.5

Tags: module, javascript, css, magento2.3.5-p1

I want to use css and js in custom module, I want to create collapse tabs in magento

so anyone can have idea please share with me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am going to use bootstrap in magento 2.3.5

Answer (score 0):

You can set in your module layout xml >

if yes please accept this post.